# Android Studio 3.4: Changing the value for a property with a final value has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I get the following warning in the Build Output console of Android Studio 3.4:

> Task :app:processDebugResources
>   Changing the value for a property with a final value has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 6.0.

Here's my build.gradle(Module:app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xscoder.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Parse
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.18.6"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.18.6"
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'


    // CircleImageView
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

    // Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.7@aar'

    // Google & Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Everything is fine, the app runs smoothly, but what I'm wondering is when Gradle 6.0 will be available, so what may cause that task deprecation?

Comment: Gradle is extremely unspecific at times. The depreciation of RegisterResGeneratingTask also resulted in straight out confusing warnings. It's not your code (unless you have more you didn't include) - it's likely that of a dependency. It's fine for now if it is, there's nothing you can do about it aside wait for an update. If you create a new project (to avoid unresolved reference errors) and try adding one dependency and building, you can at least pinpoint the source. Not exactly the most elegant method though

Comment: @Zoe thanks, I got it, it may be because of one or more dependencies

Comment: While I can't give an answer on how to fix this (Google will have to), debugging AGP internals revealed that for some reason it tries to (re)set `ProcessAndroidResources.getManifestFiles()` property to the same value it already has. This should work in all Gradle 5.x (with warning), and will probably throw an exception in 6.x; so AGP 3.4.x simply won't run on 6.x.

Answer (score 3):

Try to `Run` this may this will help

```
./gradlew clean
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/*
```